# c++ Eigen::VectorXd initialized in a loop

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, eigen3

I have a for loop in which i initialize randomly 3 eigen vectors like

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
  Eigen::VectorXd state(mysize), dstate(mysize),  tau(mysize);
  state.setRandom();
  tau.setRandom();

   double time = 0.0;
    dstate = dosomething(time, state, tau);

   }
```

Everything work quite well but the memory grows indefinitely. I know that using `Eigen::VectorXd` the memory is reserved on the heap but when I initialize again should by released, right?. I also tried to resize the vectors to zero at the end of the loop but nothing change the occupied memory grows.
My question is, why this happen?

Comment: How do you determine that there is a memory leak? Looking at the total memory allocated to the program is not necessarily reliable. Use e.g. valgrind or address/leak sanitizer. It will tell you exactly which allocation is leaked if there is one.

Comment: How do you know the leak is not caused by dosomething?

Comment: I used valgrind to check the memory leaks. But if I put  Eigen::VectorXd state(mysize), dstate(mysize),  tau(mysize); outside the loop the memory remain almost constant during the execution instead in the when the declaration is in the loop at the end I have 2 GB allocated on the heap, I saw this from the report in valgrind

Comment: I am not able to confirm your observation. Please share the full source code of your example.

Comment: I cannot share the full source code for several reason, one of those is that the source code has a lot of lines of code. But what I would like to know is the reason why if i put the definition of Eigen::VectorXd in the loop the memory grows and if it is outside the memory usage remain constant. Could it depends on dosomething()? if yes could you give me an example of when this could happen?

Comment: Are you able to run this on Linux?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 18